# Safely limiting PHP session space

Tags: php, performance, session, strace

I can't seem to find this information anywhere so I thought I ask here.

Currently I have my PHP session path (session.save_path) set to a folder on the server hard drive.

I created a simple PHP program like the following:

```
<?php echo "TEST"; ?>
```

then I executed it with strace and the process in strace logs that took the longest is `shmdt()`, and when I matched the numbers up, it referred to an sem file in session.save_path.

One way I can try to alleviate this problem is to create a ram disk just for php session files but I want to be able to add a configuration entry to the PHP config file itself so PHP understands that it has so much space to work with before deleting old entries.

What configuration entry do I need to accomplish this?

and if possible, what configuration entries could I use to eliminate the `shmdt()` call?

I tested my script in PHP version 5.5.29.

Comment: By "server hard drive", do you mean the server that is running PHP? Or on an nfs file server?

Comment: yes. everything was tested on the server without a connection to anything external.  (hard drive contains the running php file as well as the session folder)

Comment: You're using the default session handler? What was the name of the sem file? And are you using opcache?

Comment: Actually, if that was the entirety of the script that got flagged with `shmdt`, it seems unlikely that it'd be session related, because you're not actually starting a session (so the session handling support shouldn't kick in). This is pretty weird, becuase `shmdt` is only used in three places: opcache, and the shmop and sysvshm extensions. Any chance you can get a stack trace of whatever's calling `shmdt`?

Comment: I'm not using opcache at all, but I do have the shmop extension installed with PHP. could that cause it?

Comment: Could be? But if you're not actually *using* shmop, it shouldn't ever be called. This is where a backtrace would be really handy.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you're trying is to prevent session files are stored in excess in the session folder (session.save_path).

If you have access to the PHP configuration file (php.ini), you must adjust the value of "session.gc_maxlifetime" to the maximum duration you require so that the files are deleted from the server.

PHP Documentation: 
http://ar.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime

To assign a space to "RAM disk", requires root access to the server. If this is your case, you have to do following:

1. Create a folder for your sessions:

```
mkdir /var/sessions
```

2. Edit the "fstab" file:

```
vi /etc/fstab
```

3. Create the entry of your RAM disk mapped to that folder:

```
none   /var/sessions   tmpfs   defaults,size=50M   1   2
```

4. Save changes in "fstab".
5. Mount the new RAM disk:

```
mount -a
```

NOTE: in "4" point, I am assigning 50 Mb of RAM space. You must allocate the space that you have available for user use in the server RAM.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I already have ram drives setup on my server and active. While session.gc_maxlifetime might minimize the risk of exceeding disk space, I feel there's a better answer than to take chances (maybe if there was some kind of panic/reduce-files  setting if disk usage exceeds x bytes)